# Why do nails on a chalkboard physically make us cringe?

Tags: soundwaves, goosebumps, misophonia

Because the ossicles in my ears are fused, I'm profoundly hearing impaired and don't quite understand the complaints of those suffering from misophonia or hyperacusis because I think it's a miracle to just hear!

Needless to say, most noises don't bother me. However, I do notice that I react to **hearing nails on a chalkboard** the same way the majority of the population does: **psychical cringes and goosebumps up the spine.** What causes this?

**How does a sound that's not harmful to hearing trigger such a physical reaction?**

**If I'm not hearing it at the same frequency or pitch as everyone else, how does it have this almost uniform impact?**

Comment: Can whoever finds an answer please also provide a treatment for this medical condition of ours? ;P. I'm freaking out on a daily basis because of this...